# hp compaq 8510p laptop starts but no screen display

Tags: laptop, windows-10, hardware-failure, laptop-display

I am using hp compaq 8510p about 3 years and this problem occurred for the first time. I was using windows 7 and my laptop was working fine.

Then I decided to upgrade to windows 10. I installed it. My laptop was working fine. Suddenly a notification came that and catalyst has stopped working.... before I could read the whole message my screen turned like an old mario game and suddenly my screen goes black. And now every time I start my system the fans run and lights glow but my screen remains black. Please help me...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on a Dell desktop. I could still see the windows symbol and then it went black (with the mouse cursor still visible).
First you need to get into repair mode. The only way I found is to unplug the power cord while windows is loading (on a laptop you should remove the battery). The next time it will try to repair and give you troubleshooting options. You might try if "safe mode with networking" is working, then uninstall catalyst (by "changing" catalyst install manager).
If that does not help, you might try msconfig and disable all NON Microsoft services and ALL start programs- and restart. If that works you will need to find out which of the services is creating the problem by enabling some, then restarting, then some more until you find the ONE that is creating the problem.
If none of the above works, your best chance is to revert to Win 7 (from the troubleshooting screen). You may still have a black screen then, but getting into safe mode with F8 should work, and then try the above. Very frustrating and long process.... Good luck.